# Solidity contract compilation on open github repository

Tags: solidity

What are the ways to check that all the .sol files in a github repository can be successfully compiled (like travis, circle etc)?

Basically I want to check that in an open repository there is no compilation error in the contracts being pushed. If contract compilation fails, PR/build fails.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? There is definitely a compiler error, so it sounds like you are making some wrong assumption here. If there is no compiler error then can you show all steps and expected output and actual output you are doing.

Comment: It's like we consider in travis that all tests are running fine to pass a build, similarly all contracts are successfully compiled for passing the build. I hope now you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Without an integrated tool it is difficult and you're left to clone and verify locally. Perhaps [Truffle Teams](https://truffleframework.com/teams) is worth a look for your use case.

Comment: Seems a better solution. I am analysing if it can work the way i want. Thanks for a great suggestion !

Comment: It says: "Currently, Truffle Teams only supports the native truffle development network." ...... Mine is not a truffle project.